# Flask-restful doesn't work. Parsing not happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

Please help me with the program. I'm learning flask_restful to write an API. For some reason, when accessed via POST, the request returns this: **{'message': "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."}**.

**api.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api()

sdelki = {1: {'status': True, 'coins': 3}, 2: {'status': False, 'coins': 432}}


class Main(Resource):
    def get(self, s_id=0):
        if s_id == 0:
            return {0: 0}
        return sdelki[s_id]

    def post(self, s_id=0):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('status', type=bool)
        parser.add_argument('coins', type=int)
        sdelki[s_id] = parser.parse_args()
        return sdelki


api.add_resource(Main, '/api/main/<int:s_id>', '/api/main/', '/api/main')
api.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host="127.0.0.1")
```

**local_test.py**

```
import requests

res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/main/5', {'status': True, 'coins': 232})
print(res.json())
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type